# VSTS - Rule to enforce Task linking to User Stories

Tags: azure-devops

Is it possible to create a rule (or some other mechanism) so that Tasks are required to be linked to User Stories when created?  I have run into a situation where I have a large number of orphan Tasks and it becomes difficult to back-track to associate them with the appropriate User Stories.  Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no build in support but using WebHooks and an endpoint like an Azure function you can build your own validation mechanism.

For example, you can [configure a WebHook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/service-hooks/services/webhooks) in VSTS to listen for events and send these to a public endpoint. One event type is for [Work Items](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/service-hooks/events#work-item). The endpoint can be any type of public endpoint, [for example an Azure Function](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/buckh/2016/03/31/using-vs-team-services-web-hooks-with-azure-functions/).

In your Azure Function you get the JSON representation of the work item that gets created. You can then use the [VSTS REST API](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/overview) to check if your task is linked to a user story.

If validation fails it's up to you what to do. You could send an email, post to Slack, add a comment to the Tasks history or anything else you can come up with. Not ideal but better then nothing.

Comment: Thanks so much for suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn’t way to do it. There is a user voice that you can vote: [A rule of require specified link with specified work item type when creating a work item](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/33032386-a-rule-of-require-specified-link-with-specified-wo)

You can add it to the work policy that everyone need to obey.